# How to make an iOS like App Store card animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv7sn.jpg)  iOS 13 App Store's card like transition in Flutter?

Comment: Maybe you can do something like this using [Hero Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be9UH1kXFDw). Or at least it's a good starting point.

Comment: Maybe this link can be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575091/possible-to-copy-ios-app-store-transition-using-flutter