# Flutter GestureDetector if swiping down to dismiss

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, gesturedetector

I would like to be able to swipe down to dismiss but with the `Hero-Animation`.

I tried using a `GestureDetector` like this:

```
  body: GestureDetector(
    onVerticalDragDown: (details) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
    child:
```

The animation looks fine with this but the problem is that it is `poping` at almost any gesture. What I would like to have is that it is only popping if the user is actually swiping down.

There should be some `finished` property as well so the animation is canceled if the user is not fully swiping down. Is this possible and if so, how? I couldn't find anything on this..

The desired outcome should look like this:

[Desired Animation](https://gofile.io/d/FAdJoA)

As you can see I can swipe down and also cancel the `pop` by not fully swiping down.

**Current Animation:**

[Screenvideo](https://gofile.io/d/CsBNBS)

By clicking the close button the animation is working just fine.
However if I start dragging, the animation should start, and if I end it, it should `pop`, or I could also cancel the animation and the animation is restored to the normal screen.

This is my code if that is full code if that is helping:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragDown: (details) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Hero(
              tag: month.name + 'background',
              // transitionOnUserGestures: true,
              child: Container(
                // color: CustomColors.darkCustom,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: CustomColors.darkCustom,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              right: 30,
              top: 15,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Hero(
                  // transitionOnUserGestures: true,
                  tag: month.name + 'close',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 45,
                    width: 45,
                    child: RawMaterialButton(
                      fillColor: CustomColors.lightGreyCustom,
                      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                      // elevation: 10,
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/close.white.svg',
                          height: 25, width: 25),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SafeArea(
                  bottom: false,
                  child: SizedBox(height: 20),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 45, top: 45, bottom: 35),
                      child: Hero(
                        // transitionOnUserGestures: true,
                        tag: month.name + 'text',
                        // sized box to prevent flickering bug
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 200,
                          // material is need for Hero + Text
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            child: Text(
                              month.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 28,
                                fontFamily: Fonts.glossAndBloom,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Hero(
                  tag: month.name + 'frame',
                  child: Container(
                    height: Constants.width(context) - 60,
                    width: Constants.width(context) - 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**In Swift I managed to achieve the animation with this code:**

```
@objc private func handlePan(gestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // calculate the progress based on how far the user moved
    let translation = panGR.translation(in: nil)
    let progress = translation.y / 2 / view.bounds.height
    
    switch panGR.state {
    case .began:
        // begin the transition as normal
        self.dismissView()
        break
    case .changed:
        
        Hero.shared.update(progress)
        
    default:
        // finish or cancel the transition based on the progress and user's touch velocity
        if progress + panGR.velocity(in: nil).y / view.bounds.height > 0.3 {
            self.dismissView()
            Hero.shared.finish()
        } else {
            Hero.shared.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted for using tempolery video link, try using permenant

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use DragEndDetails of the callback function.
Simple example will be:

```
onVerticalDragEnd: (endDetails) {
              double velocity = endDetails.primaryVelocity;
              if (velocity > 0 ){                              
               Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            },
```

In this case if you hold the drag gesture at the end it will not pop because velocity will be equal to 0.

Edit:

This is an simple example of implementing animation on drag details. On DragUpdate container height will be adjusted but with limit of max:300 to min:100. On DragEnd depends on either you swipe up or down the container height will be set to max or min.

```
class AnimatedContainerApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedContainerAppState createState() => _AnimatedContainerAppState();
}

class _AnimatedContainerAppState extends State<AnimatedContainerApp> {
  double height = 300;
  bool gestureUp = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final maxHeight = 300.0;
    final minHeight = 100.0;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AnimatedContainer Demo'),
        ),
        body: Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,             
         child:AnimatedContainer(
          color: Colors.red,
            height: height,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            child: GestureDetector(
               onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                 setState((){
                  if (0 < details.delta.dy)
                    gestureUp = false;
                  else
                    gestureUp = true;
                  height -= details.delta.dy;
                  if (height > maxHeight)
                      height = maxHeight;
                  else if (height < minHeight)
                      height = minHeight;
                  });     
                },
                onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
                  setState((){
                      if (gestureUp) {
                        height = maxHeight;
                      } else {
                        height = minHeight;
                      }
                    });     
                },
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: actualy you should use [kMinFlingVelocity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/kMinFlingVelocity-constant.html) or some similar constants

Comment: ok this kind of works in the way that `pop` is only called when it actually should be called. However, by dragging down, the animation is not starting. when completing the whole dragging, it animtes. But it is not 100% the desired animation. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Chris Yes. In that case, you should handle animation with `onVerticalDragUpdate` callback

Comment: @hyobbb how would I do that??

Comment: It depends on how you want to implement the animation behavior using `DragUpdateDetails`. check out this api doc. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html

Comment: @hyobbb ok thanks but I am quite lost here. How would I implement this? using the above code?

Comment: @Chris I edited the answer with some example that might help you.

Comment: @hyobbb thanks for your help but I think this is not really accomplishing what I want. I have several different `Hero-Widgets` inside a `Stack` on my Screen. All of this needs to be animated. So only animating the container will not do the trick I think :( I wonder if flutter/Hero has this feature

Comment: Yep. It is an example to give you an idea how to deal with onDragUpdate situation. As you are using stack you can wrap your widget with `Positioned` widget and modify top or bottom parameter